# How to derive a child class when parent's internal representation is not known?

Tags: perl, oop

What is the best way to derive a class from a class that someone else wrote, and which internal representation (i.e. its object hash) must be assumed unknown? The problem I see is that the obvious way:

```
package Employee;
use parent 'Person';    # inherits from Person

# Override constructor
sub new {
    my ($class, $first_name, $last_name, $id, $title) = @_;

    # Call the constructor of the parent class, Person.
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new( $first_name, $last_name );
    # Add few more attributes
    $self->{id}   = $id;  # <-- I cannot know if 'id' is already used by parent
    $self->{title} = $title; # <-- same here: 'title' might be in use
    return bless $self, $class;
}
```

runs into the problem that the `$self` hash of the parent must be assumed a black box (even if we know the representation (attributes) today, we cannot know if the author of the module will change it in the future). Then, if the child tries to insert its own attributes into the `$self` hash, it might overwrite the parents attributes with the same name.

Comment: It sounds like you may want composition actually (not inheritance). Build an object of that other (would-be parent) class in your class (in an attribute or as class-data) so you can use that class as needed. Otherwise write your class as you wish.

Comment: @zdim Yes, but I also want to do `$obj->parent_method_xx(...)` without having to write wrappers for all the parents methods in the child. That's why I think using `AUTOLOAD()` might be a solution.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Moose will write the wrappers for you if you use `handles` (the argument can be an array or a regex, among others; a regex will find all the methods in that class matching the pattern.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using `OVERLOAD()` and object composition:

```
package Employee;
use Person;

sub new {
    my ($class, $first_name, $last_name, $id, $title) = @_;

    my $parent = Person->new( $first_name, $last_name );
    my $self = { 
        parent => $parent, id => $id, title => $title
    };
    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub AUTOLOAD {
    my ( $self, @args ) = @_;
    our $AUTOLOAD;
    my $sub_name = $AUTOLOAD;
    $sub_name =~ s/^Employee:://;
    my $parent = $self->{parent};
    my $parent_sub = $parent->can( $sub_name );
    if ($parent_sub ) {
        return $parent_sub->( $parent, @args);
    }
}

# More child methods follows here..
1;
```

Comment: When you add autoloading to an object, it's good to also override `can` to return true for methods implemented in the autoloader.

Comment: If you don't mind listing the methods you want to be able to call, you can manually create them with code like `BEGIN { for (@DELEGATE_METHODS ) { no strict refs; *{__PACKAGE__."::$_"} = sub {  shift->{parent}->$_(@_) } }`.  Then you don't have to mess around with AUTOLOAD.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use "inside-out objects" for this. Even if you don't know anything about the parent class's object representation, one thing that you can count on at least is that every object is a *reference*. That means, since every reference has a unique [refaddr](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util#refaddr), that you can store your own properties for an object in a hash, keyed by the object's refaddr, and never have to put anything "inside" the object at all.

Doing this yourself properly is possible, but a bit tricky if you're not familiar with the details, so I would recommend using [MooseX::NonMoose::InsideOut](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX::NonMoose::InsideOut) or [MooX::InsideOut](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooX::InsideOut) in your subclass to do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks! I am not familiar with "inside-out" objects, it might be my best option. I was thinking about not using use parent at all, and keep a copy of the parent object in the child, and use `UNIVERSAL->can()` from an `AUTOLOAD()` method to dispatch to the parent, but it might very well have drawbacks that I am not aware of yet.

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable option too. It's not quite subclassing, but it works :)